# Contagem de Números usando Array em C

Tags: c, array, string, contador

Como fazer para contar inteiros usando um array em C, nesse modelo:

Entrada> duas strings com "inteiros"

ex: 8 15

Saída> Um string com os números do intervalo, inclusivo:

ex: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15.

Provavelmente uma dúvida básica, mas sou iniciante na área ainda.

Obrigado!

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Você precisa necessariamente em C ou pode ser C++?

Comment: Isso tá com uma cara de dever de casa... Você está com alguma dificuldade específica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá, se for em C que você precisa então segue:

```
//Define a entrada dos 2 valores
char rangeStr[] = "8 15";
//Define a variavel que vai armazenar os valores convertidos
int rangeInt[2] = { 0, 0 };

//Tokeniza a string com delimitador ' '
char* splitedRange = strtok(rangeStr, " ");

//Define a variavel de contagem para garantir que apenas 2 valores sejam atribuidos
int i = 0;
//inicializa o loop para extrair os valores entre ' ' e garantir que sejam até 2
while (splitedRange && i < 2)
{
    //verifica se o valor recebido é numérico
    if (isdigit(*splitedRange))
        rangeInt[i] = atoi(splitedRange);
    splitedRange = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}
//Cria o looping em cima dos dois valores entregues
for (int start = rangeInt[0]; start <= rangeInt[1]; start++)
    printf("%d\n", start);
```